# Problemas com query no XPath

Tags: php, xpath

HTML:

```
<div align="center"><center>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#006090" valign="top" align="center"><p align="center"><strong><font face="Tahoma"
    size="2" color="#FFFFFF">Selecione a Semana</font></strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center" height="1" bgcolor="#22A7D2"><form method="POST">
      <dl>
        <div align="center">
        <dt><font size="2" face="Tahoma">&nbsp;<font color="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" name="EDR" size="20"
          style="background-color: rgb(34,167,210); color: rgb(34,167,210); border: medium none"
          value="Tudo"></font></font></dt>
        </div>
        <dd>&nbsp;</dd>
        <div align="center">
        <dt><strong><font size="2" face="Tahoma">Semana:</font> </strong></dt>
        </div><div align="center">
        <dt><font size="2" face="Tahoma"></font></dt>
        </div>
        <dt><font size="2" face="Tahoma"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong><font color="#FFFFFF"><select name="Inicio"
          size="1" style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255); color: rgb(0,0,128)">
            <option value="16/2/2015">16/2/2015 - 22/2/2015 </option>
            <option value="9/2/2015">9/2/2015 - 15/2/2015 </option>
```

**OBS:O html continua com muito mais opções,mas até aqui já da para ter uma idéia.**
A query que estou tentando utilizar para pegar o **value** das **options**(TODAS):

```
//select[name='Inicio']/option/@value
```

**OBS:Não consegui testar a query para ver se funcionava.**
Quando tento dar echo no php:

```
echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Erro retornado:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\
```

Imagino que estou errando na **query**,tenho **dúvida** se preciso **percorrer o html todo** com a query para chegar na options ou p**osso ir direto pro select como fiz**.
Alguém sabe onde está o erro?

Comment: O que retorna um var_dump de $nodes ?

Comment: @gmsantos object(DOMNodeList)#41 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Rodolfo, a resposta do @JJoao resolveu seu problema? Não esqueça de marcá-la como correta caso sim ou forneça mais esclarecimentos do que deu errado.

Answer (score 1):

Quase: falta uma `@` no *name*; então a consulta, que está assim:

```
//select[name="Inicio"]/option/@value
```

Deverá ficar assim:

```
//select[@name="Inicio"]/option/@value
```

Comment: @mutlei, obrigado. (Às vezes sou um pouco lacónico de mais...)

Comment: De nada. Essa resposta estava na fila de respostas curtas, e por um bom motivo hehe.

Comment: @mutlei, eu tinha tentado responder `...[@name="Inicio"]...` mas o sistema não me deixou.